# Sklearn models: decision function vs predict_proba for roc curve

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In Sklearn, roc curve requires (y_true, y_scores). Generally, for y_scores, I feed in probabilities as outputted by a classifier's predict_proba function. But in the sklearn example, I see both predict_prob and decision_fucnction are used.

I wonder what is the difference in terms of real life model evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

The functional form of logistic regression is -

> f(x)=11+e−(β0+β1x1+⋯+βkxk)

This is what is returned by predict_proba.

The term inside the exponential i.e.

> d(x)=β0+β1x1+⋯+βkxk

is what is returned by decision_function. The "hyperplane" referred to in the documentation is

> β0+β1x1+⋯+βkxk=0

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding after reading few resources:

**Decision Function**: Gives the distances from the hyperplane. These are therefore unbounded. This can not be equated to probabilities. For getting probabilities, there are 2 solutions - Platt Scaling & Multi-Attribute Spaces to calibrate outputs using Extreme Value Theory.

**Predict Proba**: Gives the actual probabilities (0 to 1) however attribute '*probability*' has to be set to *True* while fitting the model itself. It uses Platt scaling which is known to have theoretical issues.

Refer to [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities) in documentation.